# SSA - Copy Propagation and Phi functions

Tags: optimization, graph, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, ssa

I've implemented a program that converts a control flow graph to minimal ssa (and I am pretty sure it is correct (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62984347/is-my-construction-of-ssa-correct-renaming))). Now I am trying to implement copy propagation. I've implemented it for the most part, but I am unsure what to do when the variable we are propagating is in a phi function. Suppose I have a variable I am going to propagate:

```
z_0 = y_1
```

Also, `z_0` is in a phi function:

```
z_1 = PHI(z_0, z_1)
```

Now, when propagating, what should I do to `z_0` in the phi function (because after propagation is finished, I will remove the definition of `z_0`)? Should I propagate `z_0` to the phi function? Such that the phi function looks like this?:

```
z_1 = PHI(y_1, z_1)
```

Comment: That's what you would do if you were propagating constants, right? So basically, yes. But iirc there are some corner cases with copy propagation.

Comment: @rici -- If you don't mind, what would those be?

Comment: I think the issue I was (vaguely) remembering is the lost copy problem mentioned by Preston Briggs et al in "Practical improvements to the construction and destruction of static single assignment form" (non-paywalled copies are available). You can find probably a lot more than you want to know right now about SSA by reading the SSA book, available on http://ssabook.gforge.inria.fr/latest/book.pdf (last update 2018, I notice)....

Comment: While I was looking for Briggs et al., I stumbled upon "Comparison and Evaluation of Back Translation Algorithms for Static Single Assignment Form" by Masataka Sassa, Yo Ito and Masaki Kohama (2007), which also seems interesting at first glance. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All uses of `z0` are replaced with `y1` in copy propagation. There are multiple edge cases to handle, as @rici hinted at, as copy propagation is uniquely adept at breaking phi nodes / inadvertently altering their semantics.

Some of these problems are encapsulated in the "lost copy problem" and "lost swap problem."

Comment: Would you mind providing more info on the edge cases and maybe providing some reference material? Thanks!

Comment: @santamanno I'm trying to learn more about this myself, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139050/135438

Comment: Please include the additional info - when you have it - in your answer so it can better help the poster.